# Python 3.6 - Arrays

Tags: python

print("Enter the home team's name")

home_team = input (">")

print("Enter the visitor team's name")

visitors_team = input (">")

print("How many points did the Mountaineers score in quarter 1?")

M_q1 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Fighting Irish score in quarter 1?")

F_q1 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Mountaineers score in quarter 2?")

M_q2 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Fighting Irish score in quarter 2?")

F_q2 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Mountaineers score in quarter 3?")

M_q3 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Fighting Irish score in quarter 3?")

F_q3 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Mountaineers score in quarter 4?")

M_q4 = input (">")

print("How many points did the Fighting Irish score in quarter 4?")

F_q4 = input (">")

print("Total Statistics")

```
my_list=["Quarters"," " "Mountaineers"," " "Fighting Irish"]
my_scores1 = [1, 7, 7]
my_scores2 = [2, 10, 7]
my_scores3 = [3, 0, 14]
my_scores4 = [4, 21, 0]

print("{:<5}{:^10}{:>10}".format(my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2]))
for a_list in [my_scores1, my_scores2, my_scores3, my_scores4]:
    print("{:<5}{:^10}{:>10}".format(a_list[0], a_list[1], a_list[2]))
```

I don't know how to add the last line of code to give me the totals for Mountaineers and Fighting Irish. Can you please help? I hope that I have posted this correctly to get the correct answer.

```
Total Statistics
Quarter Mountaineers Fighting Irish
1            7                 7
2           10                 7
3            0                 14
4           21                 0
Total       38                 28
```

Comment: So, you are either going to have to compute your statistics in the for-loop you already have, or do a second pass to compute the statistics and print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the lists in order to get the totals.

```
irish_total = 0
mountaineers_total = 0

for quarter in (my_scores1, my_scores2, my_scores3, my_scores4):
    mountaineers_total += quarter[1]
    irish_total += quarter[2]
```

Comment: Hi Ethan, I really appreciate your help.  when I run this code it's not getting the last line.  The Total   38   28

Comment: No prob. Yes, but no where in your code do you ever compute the totals. The total scores would be the scores for all four quarters added together. The loop I provided will do that. You could put it into the loop you already have if  you wish, or use a second loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to this programming stuff and don't understand what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: at the end is where the totals go. I have the rest I just need the last line to put this at this end.   Total 38     28

Comment: I think I understand what your asking at the top.print("How many points did the Mountaineers score in quarter 1?")

M_q1 = input (">")